# Geometry Nodes Scaling Issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transforms, geometry-nodes

I am having an issue with "Instance To Points" causing unwanted scaling and rotation of an object. These are tiny "supports" for a neon sign.
[image: Issue]

Here are the Geometry Nodes:
[image: Geometry Nodes]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you don't have to ....but providing a blend file with your problem will attract a lot more people to look at it.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X_kvLn28hPg9xRn8PX00j8Tt7ERpafl7/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can scale your instances by adding a scale instance like this:

[image]

result: [image]

but now you have more a positioning than a scaling issue... ;)

> Note: Normally you should apply your scale before using them because
> it prohibits a lot of trouble. You didn't apply the scale to your
> stand. Just select your stand, hit ctrl-a -> scale. Now you won't need
> the scale instances node ;)

Comment: That was super helpful, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome!